# Register more than one module

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to register module in dojo. I register one module in this way.

```
djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: false, modulePaths: {'module': '../../module'}
```

How can I register another module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/Path/To/Dojo.js" djConfig="isDebug:false,parseOnLoad:true></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    dojo.registerModulePath("module1",'../../module1');
    dojo.registerModulePath("module2",'../../module2');
    dojo.registerModulePath("module3",'../../module3');
</script>
```

Comment: dojo.registerModulePath works but how can i register more than one module with modulePaths: {'module': '../../module'}

Comment: try djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: false, modulePaths:{"module1": '../../module1',"module2":'../../module2'}"